# .net core linq select overload index does not work

Tags: linq, .net-core

I got a linq lambda select code that works before I added the Select index overload. Before, I got the list of records but I need the index which I use to assign a unique Id to each record. When I add with `ToList()`, I get an exception with no error/inner exception. Only way I can get the code to not throw an error is to use `.AsEnumberable()` but I need a list. I read many post that `.ToList()` works with the overload but I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my code and my attempt to fix this

```
  var emps = this.DbContext.Employees
                    .GroupJoin(this.DbContext.Depts,
                        employee => employee.EmployeeId,
                        dept => dept.EmployeeId,
                        (employee, dept) => new { employee, dept }
                    )
                    .SelectMany(
                        employee_dept_left => employee_dept_left.dept.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                        (employee_dept_left, dept) => new { employee_dept_left, dept }
                    )
                    .Join(this.DbContext.Divs,
                        emp_emp_dept => emp_emp_dept.employee_dept_left.employee.DivId,
                        division => division.DivId,
                        (emp_emp_dept, division) => new { emp_emp_dept, division }
                    )
                    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.selectedDiv))
                    .GroupBy(grouped => new
                    {
                        grouped.emp_emp_dept.employee_dept_left.employee.EmployeeId,
                        grouped.emp_emp_dept.employee_dept_left.employee.LastNm,
                        grouped.emp_emp_dept.employee_dept_left.employee.FirstNm,
                        grouped.emp_emp_dept.employee_dept_left.employee.DivId
                    })
                    .Select((joined, index) => new EmployeeViewModel
                    {
                        Id = index,
                        EmployeeId = joined.Key.EmployeeId,
                        LastNm = joined.Key.LastNm.Trim(),
                        FirstNm = joined.Key.FirstNm.Trim(),
                        DivisionId = joined.Key.DivId,
                    }).ToList();
```

The error message says

> Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I tried using `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()`:

```
List<EmployeeViewModel> test = emps.Cast<EmployeeViewModel>().ToList();
```

but this throws an exception.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem that this `Select` is not currently translatable to the SQL. You can make additional Select to solve issue with `AsEnumerable()`.

```cs
    ...
    .Select(joined => new 
    {
        EmployeeId = joined.Key.EmployeeId,
        LastNm = joined.Key.LastNm.Trim(),
        FirstNm = joined.Key.FirstNm.Trim(),
        DivisionId = joined.Key.DivisionId,
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((x, index) => new EmployeeViewModel
    {
        Id = index,
        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
        LastNm = x.LastNm,
        FirstNm = x.FirstNm,
        DivisionId = x.DivisionId,
    }).ToList();
```

And note that query is more readable in Query syntax when there are joins.

```cs
var query = 
    from employee in this.DbTracsContext.Employees
    join dept in his.DbTracsContext.Depts on employee.EmployeeId equals dept.EmployeeId into employee_dept_left
    from dept in employee_dept_left.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join division in this.DbTracsContext.Depts on employee.DivisionId equals division.DivisionId
    where string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.DivisionSelection) || filter.DivisionSelection == "0" || employee.DivisionId == filter.DivisionSelection
    group employee by new { employee.EmployeeId, employee.LastNm, employee.FirstNm, employee.DivisionId } into g
    select new
    {
        EmployeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
        LastNm = g.Key.LastNm.Trim(),
        FirstNm = g.Key.FirstNm.Trim(),
        DivisionId = g.Key.DivisionId,
    };

var emps = query
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((x, index) => new EmployeeViewModel
    {
        Id = index,
        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
        LastNm = x.LastNm,
        FirstNm = x.FirstNm,
        DivisionId = x.DivisionId,
    }).ToList();
```